# The "2Do" application shows a blue dot in app's titlebar on macOS - what is it for?

Tags: applications

What does the blue dot next to the other red/yellow/green dots do in the title bar of 2Do on macOS?
[image: Blue dot on right of normal red amber and green dots at top right of window]

Comment: What have you done to investigate it? What happens if you click on the blue dot?

Comment: Sometimes it shows, sometimes it doesn't. No apparent functionality. Not sure if it's a macOS thing or an app thing. Reading the documentation didn't help.

Comment: The blue dot is **not** a part of macOS. It was added by an app for unknown functionality. Never seen something like that before

Comment: When you click on the button, what happens?  Is it *only* on the 2Do app?  If it is, I would contact their support department because after [searching their knowledge base](https://www.2doapp.com/kb/category/mac-os-x/38/), there's no mention of it.

Answer (score 1):

The button is specific to the app "2Do" which you're running. It is not a general macOS "thing".

You are not the first person to ask why the meaning of the dot is, or what it does (if anything) when pressed. For example there's a Reddit thread about it here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/aw08z5/what_does_this_blue_button_next_to_the_traffic/

However even though the manual for 2Do shows a screenshots with this blue dot - it is not explained what the purpose of it is.

I would suggest contacting the support for 2Do to find out more!